# Debugging nodejs with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I am trying to use node-inspector to debug my nodejs app and I am having problems.  I can attach and bring up the app in chrome.  I can also navigate to my scripts and set breakpoints.  When I execute my code it will hit breakpoints but I cannot step through the code.  When I hit the step-in or step-over buttons I no longer have the ability to step or continue execution.  I am using the latest version of node-inspector and running node 0.10.  Anyone else using node-inspector and having problems?

Comment: Which specific version of node-inspector are you using? I have seen similar behavior before, but currently 0.2.0beta4 works OK with me with Chrome 26.0.1410.43.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a known issue in a previous version. It has since been fixed in the latest version maintained by StrongLoop.

https://npmjs.org/package/node-inspector